# Whether R has a Cholesky decomposition when R is a positive semi-definite?

Tags: matrices

It is no doubt that R has a Cholesky decomposition when R is a positive definite matrix.I want to ask Whether R has a Cholesky decomposition when R is a positive semi-definite?I would appreciate it if you could give an example.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes", you can find a non-constructive proof of this fact also in Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Proof_for_positive_semi-definite_matrices

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But when R is a positive definite matrix,is there any method to do a Cholesky decomposition for R?For example,in the tool of MATLAB,we know that the instruction of chol can  do a Cholesky decomposition when R is a positive definite matrix.

Comment: Yes, of course there is a method in the positive definite case, see here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Computation

Comment: In Matlab Programming, the "chol" command can be used to simply apply this to only a positive definite matrix.When it comes to a positive semi-definite matrix，“chol” fails.I want to ask if there any command in Matlab Programming that can be used to a positive semi-definite matrix?